# two analog channel affect each other in pic

Tags: embedded, pic, adc

Iam doing a project to recognize gestures by reading adc values in pic 16f73 using embedded c. Everything works fine while using single adc channel. When i use multiple channels, values are affected each other.  is this a hardware error or software problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably.  It's very likely to be one, or the other, or both.  Split problem in half.

Eliminate one at a time. Scope/meter on both analog inputs.  Change one input - does the other change too?  If it does, there is a hardware issue at least.  If not, it's software.

This is debugging 101.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hardware effect, but not an error.

From the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/30325b.pdf):

> 11.1 A/D Acquisition Requirements
>   For the A/D converter to meet its specified accuracy,
>   the charge holding capacitor (CHOLD) must be allowed
>   to fully charge to the input channel voltage level. The
>   analog input model is shown in Figure 11-2. The source
>   impedance (RS) and the internal sampling switch (RSS)
>   impedance directly affect the time required to charge
>   the capacitor CHOLD. The sampling switch (RSS)
>   impedance varies over the device voltage (VDD), see
>   Figure 11-2. The source impedance affects the offset
>   voltage at the analog input (due to pin leakage current). 
>   The maximum recommended impedance for analog sources is 10 kΩ. After the analog input channel is
>   selected (changed), the acquisition period must pass
>   before the conversion can be started.
>   To calculate the minimum acquisition time, TACQ, see
>   the PICmicro™ Mid-Range MCU Family Reference
>   Manual (DS33023). In general, however, given a maximum source impedance of 10 kΩ and at a temperature
>   of 100°C, TACQ will be no more than 16 µsec.

Answer (score 1):

It will likely be because you have high impedance sources driving all the ADC pins. When the multiplexer switches from one input to the next, any charge that is stored on the sampling capacitor of the ADC from the previous input will still be there.

If you drive each input with the output of a suitable op amp, when the ADC's multiplexer switches, the op amp is able to drive charge in or suck charge out of the sampling capacitor and the time needed for the new input you are reading can be significantly reduced. Plus, with this method you are not loading the voltage you are wanting to read.

If you cannot drive with a low impedance source, then ensure you have plenty of time for the new input's value to settle.